# Can't run Jest tests from editor in WebStorm

Tags: jestjs, webstorm

I'm looking at a file in WebStorm that contains Jest tests. I can run Jest via a run configuration and it works fine.

However, I can't right-click on a test in the editor and run it, nor do I get any gutter icons that would let me do so. I can right-click on a `describe` or `it` block and I have the option to run or debug, but it's trying to run/debug the *file*, not run the test:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from "react";
                                                                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is a new installation on a new M1 MacBook Pro, but it's got my settings synced with my other machines, so I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work like all my other WebStorm installations. (And it's not just this file, it's any test file anywhere.)

Comment: Do you have `jest` in your project dependencies? How many `package.json` files do you have in your project? normally the IDE analyses the dependencies in the `package.json` file _nearest_ to the current `.js` spec file to find the test runners available for this file. If nothing is found, no icons in the gutter are there, as WebStorm has no idea what test runner to use to start the tests

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved itself when I removed `babel-jest` from our dependencies and added `jest`, which hadn't previously been there even though the tests would run, including using the "Run tests" run config.

As @lena suggested, the problem appeared to be not having Jest in the package file.